# Klein geometry associated to a degenerate conic

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, projective-geometry

In his study of non-euclidean geometries,
Felix Klein considers the group of projective transformations
acting on the real projective plane whose extensions
to the complex projective plane preserve a given conic.

When the conic is given in homogeneous coordinates
by the equation $x^2+y^2-z^2$,
he obtains the isometry group of what is now called
the Klein model of *hyperbolic geometry*.
The conic with equation $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is related
to the group of motions of *spherical geometry*.
He also considers the group of projective
transformations preserving the pair of points
given by the intersection
of the two degenerate conics $x^2+y^2 = 0$ and $z^2 = 0$.
This leads to *affine conformal geometry*.

What geometry do we obtain if we consider
the degenerate conic $x^2+y^2=0$ given by the two lines
$x = iy$ and $x = -iy$? Is it related to conformal geometry?

All I can see is that the transformations that preserve the conic fix the origin, which probably should be sent to infinity.

**EDIT:** Some computations give the following for the matrices associated to the transformations preserving the degenerate conic.
$$
\pmatrix{ \alpha & \beta & 0 \cr
            -\beta & \alpha & 0 \cr
          \gamma & \delta & 1 \cr }
$$
So it seems that this geometry is dual to affine conformal geometry.
Does it have a name?

Comment: These are the linear transformations that take $z=0$ to itself and act by complex linear transformation on it.

Comment: @McKay I don't understand your comment. We are looking for a group of real transformations acting on real the projective plane. Even if I interpret your comment as the group of similitudes of the plane, I don't think this is right. A transformation preserving globally the two lines may not preserve the line at infinity.

Comment: Ok, projectivized, these are the projective transformations of the real projective line that preserve its usual metric, as the circle of any radius you choose to fix. Just check the linear algebra to see that the linear transformations of 3 real variables are the ones I said, and then projectivize. The group action doesn't depend on the chosen radius, so you get to pick it.

Comment: @McKay I did the computations and put the results above. Still this geometry is unknown to me.